# if-statement (CGAffineTransform) doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I'd like to make an if-condition which checks out if my scroll view is in the current rotation

`self.scrollViewImgView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;`

How can I check out if this is happened or not via an if-condition?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current orientation of your `scrollview` by writing below code:-

```
    if (CGAffineTransformIsIdentity(self.scrollViewImgView.transform)) 
    {            
        NSLog(@"transform is identity and no transformation");            
    }
    else
    {            
        NSLog(@"Rotated/Some transformation made somehow");
    }
```

Comment: Can you please mention some comments for the better answer. This will be helpful to questioner as well as other seekers. Hope you will understand my words. Thanks.

Comment: I have explained in NSLog statements dude

Comment: Good to know that, can u pls accept the answer it it was helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform` ?

```
bool CGAffineTransformEqualToTransform (
   CGAffineTransform t1,
   CGAffineTransform t2
);
```

Description  : 
Checks whether two affine transforms are equal.